# How to make custom View in Android with property of Standard view object?

Tags: android, view, android-custom-view

I want to create a view in android that has got following property:

1. Edit Text on the View like EditText View.
2. Drag and change the length of the View.
3. Text must be in the same place irrespective of the length of the View.

[image]

Surely the Custom View Class should be inheriting some standard class and overriding some function; and then the same class will be used in Activity.

I am not worried about XML features, as I'm gonna set width, height, gravity and color programmatically.

Can someone tell me how to create such a View.

Which classes to be inherited and which functions to be overwritten, in order to accomplish this?

Comment: Please explain for -1?

Answer (score 1):

To create your own view, you first have to override some subclass of `View`(or View itself) Since you want your view to have editable text, I suggest `android.widget.EditText`. This will save you a lot of work since you don't need to implement text edititng yourself. In every custom view you need to override the `onDraw()` method which is called by the framework to actually draw the view. You also need to react to layout events, i.e. orientation changes or resizing of the view. You can achieve this by overriding `onSizeChanged()` and `onMeasure()`. To react to touch events you can override `onTouch(TouchEvent e)`. These are only the most important parts, for more details refer to the official training lesson [creating custom views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) or [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html) on vogella.com.